# Manipulating endpoint json data before passing to view using express

Tags: regex, json, node.js, express

I am currently working on an express site that grabs content and data from various webservice calls. The site's navigation data used for rendering the site mega menu is coming from an endpoint that sends a nested json result set that contains the structure, hrefs, titles, used by the navigation partial to render the view.

Here is a shortened example:

```
      {
        "results": [
          {
            "title": "My Cool Site",
            "contents": [
              {
                "title": "Fruits",
                "contents": [
                  {
                    "title": "index",
                    "path": "/my-cool-site/fruits",
                    "inode": "fc5dba53-b925-4933-869b-e8c68c89e8ab",
                    "href": "/my-cool-site/fruits/index.html"
                  },
                  {
                    "title": "Apples",
                    "path": "/my-cool-site/fruits/apples",
                    "inode": "e67c34bb-9b1a-4c1b-8beb-df986827be27",
                    "href": "/my-cool-site/fruits/apples.html"
                  },
                  {
                    "title": "Bananas",
                    "path": "/my-cool-site/fruits/bananas",
                    "inode": "e67c34bb-9b1a-4c1b-8beb-df986827be27",
                    "href": "/my-cool-site/fruits/bananas.html"
                  }
                ],
                "path": "/my-cool-site/fruits",
                "inode": "89d90234-f955-4726-9116-a599b8c92138",
                "href": "/my-cool-site/fruits"
              },
              {
                "title": "Vegetables",
                "contents": [
                  {
                    "title": "index",
                    "path": "/my-cool-site/vegetables",
                    "inode": "57d1af70-a674-4ec3-965a-7eb0e0da3c75",
                    "href": "/my-cool-site/vegetables/index.html"
                  },
                  {
                    "title": "Broccoli",
                    "path": "/my-cool-site/vegetables/broccoli",
                    "inode": "57d1af70-a674-4ec3-965a-7eb0e0da3c75",
                    "href": "/my-cool-site/vegetables/broccoli.html"
                  },
                  {
                    "title": "Brussel Sprouts",
                    "path": "/my-cool-site/vegetables/brussel-sprouts",
                    "inode": "57d1af70-a674-4ec3-965a-7eb0e0da3c75",
                    "href": "/my-cool-site/vegetables/brussel-sprouts.html"
                  },

                ],
                "path": "/my-cool-site/vegetables",
                "inode": "89d90234-f955-4726-9116-a599b8c92138",
                "href": "/my-cool-site/vegetables"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

The service generating the nav tree is used for multiple sites, so you can see that for some data like the 'href': the values contain a context path of '/my-cool-site' that I would like to remove from the navigation. e.g., when I render the nav links, the node for apples should have an **href ='/fruits/apples.html'** not **'/my-cool-site/fruits/apples.html'** so, how would I do a replacement on the href values wherever they happen to appear?

How would be the best way to accomplish this? In my controller / route, I am making a call to get the data, then passing the nav object to my view.

```
    client.get(navEndPointUrl, function(nav, response) {
      res.render('templateName', {
          nav: nav 
      });
    });
```

I am new to node/express, so I am looking for examples on best way to handle this. Handle it in the view? Pass the nav object to a lodash / underscore function? For the latter, I was having trouble with finding the needle in the haystack when it could appear in many different nested locations (e.g., some of these links may be under 4-5 nested nodes in the json) and also need to return the entire json object, not just pieces of it. Would it be preferable to use JSON.parse with some sort of regex? I don't know, I am in a bit over my head with this one.

For the record, I expect there will be all sorts of these items coming up with this project, so any guidance on making this a more generalized solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can think of a few ways to do this in a clean generic way. What template engine are you using?

Comment: I am using Dust http://www.dustjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removes occurrences of `/my-cool-site` from `path` and `href` object values.

```
function formatResults(data, path, keys) {
    function format(data) {
        var result = {}
        if (_.isObject(data)) {
            _.forOwn(data, function (value, key) {
                if (_.contains(keys, key)) {
                    value = value.replace(path, '');
                }
                result[key] = format(value);
            });
        } else if (_.isArray(data)) {
            result = _.map(array, format);
        } else {
            result = data;
        }
        return result;
    }

    return format(data);
}

var formattedResults = formatResults(json, '/my-cool-site', ['path', 'href']);

console.log(formattedResults);
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/sq1qeojp/1/**

Iterate over the results object as you normally would in your template.

Answer (score 0):

**Handlebars:**

[Handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars) might be a good fit, taking advantage of the helpers and/or partials feature to process your `href` properties. Your code might look something like this:

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');

Handlebars.registerHelper('relative_to', function(rootPath) {
    var relativePath = this.href;
    if (relativePath.indexOf(rootPath) === 0) {
        relativePath = relativePath.substr(rootPath.length);
    }
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(relativePath);
});

var context = {
    contents: [{
        "title": "index",
        "path": "/my-cool-site/fruits",
        "inode": "fc5dba53-b925-4933-869b-e8c68c89e8ab",
        "href": "/my-cool-site/fruits/index.html"
    }]
};
var source = "{{#contents}}<a href={{relative_to '/my-cool-site'}}>{{title}}</a>{{/contents}}";
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

console.log(template(context));
```

Which outputs:

```
<a href=/fruits/index.html>index</a>
```

**Dust.js:**

It looks like Dust.js has similar functionality in the form of filters: http://www.dustjs.com/docs/filter-api/ And helpers: http://www.dustjs.com/guides/dust-helpers/ if you want to specify parameters.

Dust.js is really quite nice:

```
function relativeTo(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    return chunk.tap(function(data) {
        var relativePath = data;
        if (relativePath.indexOf(params.path) === 0) {
            relativePath = relativePath.substr(params.path.length);
        }
        return relativePath;
    }).render(bodies.block, context).untap();
}
dust.helpers.relativeTo = relativeTo;

var data = {
    "contents": [{
        "title": "index",
        "href": "/my-cool-site/fruits/index.html"
    }]
};

var source = '{#contents}<a href="{@relativeTo path="/my-cool-site"}{href}{/relativeTo}">{title}</a>{/contents}';
var compiled = dust.compile(source, "intro");
dust.loadSource(compiled);

dust.render("intro", data, function(err, out) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(out);
});
```

**Update:** It looks like Dust.js can even interpolate your helper parameters from the data context. So building off the code above you could do something like this:

```
data.relativePath = "/my-cool-site";
var source = '{#contents}<a href="{@relativeTo path=relativePath}{href}{/relativeTo}">{title}</a>{/contents}';
```

That's really awesome :)

Comment: Thanks for the example  - certainly looks like this would get the job done. I do wonder if I should be doing this in the view? I guess that is more of a philosophical question, but is there an approach for doing this farther upstream? e.g.,  so that by the time I use the data in the views I am just outputting the {href} rather than using lots of inline filters / helpers?

Comment: It's really up to you if you want to do this in the view or further upstream. @Moogs has a nice answer for the upstream option. Philosophically, I don't think you should be changing or processing your data for the convenience of the presentation/app layer, the burden should be on your view (or view controller) to format the data the way it needs.

Comment: Wow, dust lets you use interpolated data as parameters to your helpers. I've updated my answer above. You've effectively sent me on a little play-with-Dust.js session with this question. I think I like it a lot. Thanks :)

Comment: Great, thanks for the feedback and examples. If it were up to me, I would have the nav api response return the data so the presentation layer would not need to modify, but in lieu of that, it looks like I have a few options for reformatting so that I can use it. I am leaning toward handling it before it hits the view, but I certainly appreciate your answer as well. Thanks again.